# How to Babel Transpile Object.entries/values in Aurelia CLI app?

Tags: babeljs, aurelia, transpiler, ecmascript-2017

When using IE11, I get errors like below anywhere my code uses Object.entries or Object.values:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'...

My problem I figure stems from the code not being transpiled to ES5, but wasn't sure how to check or change my project settings for transpiling/Babel when using the Aurelia CLI.

Looking into it further, I believe the Babel/settings packaged with Aurelia don't support Object.entries/values (or other proposed ES2017 options) so I installed `babel-preset-es2017` and `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` per another thread - [Babel support for Object.entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090153/babel-support-for-object-entries)

However, I wasn't able to figure out how to update the project to include these for transpiling. Adding in `transform-runtime` in the `aurelia.json` or `.babelrc` file breaks the `au run` and simply adding `es2017` to the `.babelrc` file didn't seem to do anything. I was also looking at the `jsconfig.json` and `transpile.js` files, but couldn't figure out a solution.

`aurelia.json` file:

```
...
"transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
        "plugins": [
            "transform-es2015-modules-amd",
            "transform-runtime" <---tried
        ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
},
...
```

`.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleIds": false,
    "comments": false,
    "compact": false,
    "code": true,
    "presets": ["es2015-loose", "stage-1", "es2017"], <---tried
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-flow",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-runtime" <---tried
    ]
}
```

Adding the `transform-runtime` in either results in the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users...\src\babel-runtime\helpers\classCallCheck.js'

Not sure why I'm getting this error or if fixing it would help, but my guess could be because of the `"source": src/**/*.js` in `aurelia.json`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Object.values` will be part of ES201**7**, it's not part of ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: @FelixKling it wasn't clear to me initially what you were commenting on in pointing that out, but read it over and saw the error. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was installing the following plugin by doing `npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2017-object-entries --save-dev`, which transpiles object.entries and object.values.

The `.babelrc` file then looked like this:

```
{
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleIds": false,
    "comments": false,
    "compact": false,
    "code": true,
    "presets": ["es2015-loose", "stage-1"],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-flow",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-es2017-object-entries"
    ]
}
```

Additionally, according to the Babeljs.io (https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/), it appears `babel-preset-es2017` does not included a plugin/support for object.entries/values. Also, the purpose of `babel-tranform-runtime` appears to be for something different from what I needed and is not part of my solution.